Why is MOND's standard interpolating function form resemble a Lorentz transformation?
MOND's standard interpolating function
$\mu \left(\frac{a}{a_0}\right) = 1/ \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{a_0}{a}\right)^2}$
with $a_0$ being a constant
resembles the form of a Lorentz gamma factor
$\gamma = 1/ \sqrt{1- \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}$
with $c$ being a constant.
Why is this the case? There are other proposals for MOND's interpolating function, but why does the Lorentz gamma factor take this particular form? I am not asking about the derivation of the Lorentz gamma factor, but about the reason for its form.

These do not seem to be very similar, and I don't expect them to be, they describe different things. Also, in your MOND formula, the constant ($a_0$) is in the numerator, while in the Lorentz factor, the constant ($c$) is in denumerator.
